# SetInterval to do carousel. Two similar snippet, one is right, the other is wrong. Why?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am doing a carousel sample using JavaScript. Is there any difference between

```
        index++;
        index == imgList.length && (index = 0);
        show(index);
```

and

```
    index++;
    show(index);
    index == imgList.length - 1 && (index = -1);
```

Because the code above can work,code below cannot.
Here is all the code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var numList = document.getElementById("numbers").getElementsByTagName("li");
  var imgList = document.getElementById("imgs").getElementsByTagName("li");
  var containBox = document.getElementById("box");
  var index = 0;
  var timer = play = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
    numList[i].index = i;
    numList[i].onmouseover = function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
      show(this.index);
    };
  }

  function show(a) {
    index = a;
    var opacity = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
      imgList[i].style.opacity = 0;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) numList[i].className = "";
    numList[index].className = "current";
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      opacity += 2;
      imgList[index].style.opacity = opacity / 100;
      opacity == 100 && clearTimeout(timer);
    }, 20);
  }

  function autoPlay() {
    play = setInterval(function() {
      index++;
      show(index);
      index == imgList.length - 1 && (index = -1);
      //                index++;
      //                index == imgList.length && (index = 0);
      //                show(index);
    }, 2000);
  }
  autoPlay();

  containBox.onmouseover = function() {
    clearInterval(play);
  }

  containBox.onmouseout = function() {
    autoPlay();
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 445px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#imgs {
  position: relative;
}

#imgs li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#imgs img {
  width: 440px;
  height: 220px;
}

#numbers {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 190px;
}

#numbers li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #F90;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: rgb(232, 227, 227);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#numbers .current {
  color: white;
  background-color: #f60;
}

#imgs li {
  opacity: 0;
}

#imgs .current {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <ul id="imgs">
    <li class="current"><img src="01.jpg" alt="01.jpg">1</li>
    <li><img src="02.jpg" alt="02.jpg">2</li>
    <li><img src="03.jpg" alt="03.jpg">3</li>
    <li><img src="04.jpg" alt="04.jpg">4</li>
    <li><img src="05.jpg" alt="05.jpg">5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="numbers">
    <li class="current">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I code below, I debug in chrome devtools finding that when the `index` first became 4 in line `index = a`, then got error. I have been working on it for three hours. Help！

Comment: Well of course they're different. If `index` is incremented such that its value is the length of the array, then it should be reset to zero **before** calling `show()`.

Comment: Sorry I'm new fresher.I think by using the wrong code, when `index == imgList.length - 1`, `index` got the value `-1`, and then execute `setInterval()'s function` again, by `index++`, it can be `0` before calling `show()`. Can you please be more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your index back to 0 so that it can loop back

```
function autoPlay() {
    play = setInterval(function() {
        index = index > 4 ? index +1 : 0;
        show(index);
    }, 2000);
}
autoPlay();
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var numList = document.getElementById("numbers").getElementsByTagName("li");
  var imgList = document.getElementById("imgs").getElementsByTagName("li");
  var containBox = document.getElementById("box");
  var index = 0;
  var timer = play = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
    numList[i].index = i;
    numList[i].onmouseover = function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
      show(this.index);
    };
  }

  function show(a) {
    index = a;
    var opacity = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
      imgList[i].style.opacity = 0;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) numList[i].className = "";
    numList[index].className = "current";
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      opacity += 2;
      imgList[index].style.opacity = opacity / 100;
      opacity == 100 && clearTimeout(timer);
    }, 20);
  }

  function autoPlay() {

    play = setInterval(function() {
      index = index < 4? index+1 : 0;
      show(index);
    }, 2000);
  }
  autoPlay();

  containBox.onmouseover = function() {
    clearInterval(play);
  }

  containBox.onmouseout = function() {
    autoPlay();
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 445px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#imgs {
  position: relative;
}

#imgs li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#imgs img {
  width: 440px;
  height: 220px;
}

#numbers {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 190px;
}

#numbers li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #F90;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: rgb(232, 227, 227);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#numbers .current {
  color: white;
  background-color: #f60;
}

#imgs li {
  opacity: 0;
}

#imgs .current {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <ul id="imgs">
    <li class="current"><img src="01.jpg" alt="01.jpg">1</li>
    <li><img src="02.jpg" alt="02.jpg">2</li>
    <li><img src="03.jpg" alt="03.jpg">3</li>
    <li><img src="04.jpg" alt="04.jpg">4</li>
    <li><img src="05.jpg" alt="05.jpg">5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="numbers">
    <li class="current">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But by using the wrong code, when `index == imgList.length - 1`, `index` got the value `-1`, and then execute `setInterval()` again, by `index++`, it can be  `0` before calling `show()`.